# Multiple dropdown values inserting in a single row not in multiple row

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

In this code when i selected multiple values from dropdown it is stoing in a single row but i like to apply value in each row so please anybody help me.
Actual result:

```
id    game
1.    cricket,football,tennis
```

Expecting result:

```
id         game
1            cricket
2            football
```

code -

```
                <html>
                <body>
                  <?php
                     if(isset($_POST['submit']))
                     {
                    $query=mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
                       mysql_select_db("freeze",$query);
                       $choice=$_POST['game'];
                      $choice1=implode(',',$choice);
                      mysql_query("insert into tb values('','$choice1')");
                         }
                      ?>
                        <form method="post" action="multipleselect.php">
                           Select your favourite game:<br/>
                        <select name="game[]" multiple="multiple">
                              <option>Football</option>
                                   <option>Volleyball</option>
                                       <option>Badminton</option>
                                        <option>Cricket</option>
                                           <option>Cricket1</option>
                                             <option>Cricket2</option>
                                             <option>Cricket3</option>
                                                 <option>Cricket34</option>
                    </select>
             <input type="submit" name="submit">
                  </form>
                  </body>
                 </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is inserting them all in 1 row, because you are imploding your `$_POST['game']`

```
$choice=$_POST['game'];
$choice1=implode(',',$choice);
mysql_query("insert into tb values('','$choice1')");
```

You need to loop over each `$_POST['game']` value

```
foreach($_POST['game'] as $choice){
    mysql_query("insert into tb values('','$choice')");
}
```

---

note, your query is open to SQL injection, make sure to sanitize your data before inserting into your db. Also, `mysql_*` are deprecated, so you should update to `mysqli` or `PDO` - http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

Answer (score 3):

First of all, please don't use `mysql_*` as it's deprecated, use `mysqli_` or `PDO` instead.

now if you just want the values of options then do it like this

```
<select name="game[]" multiple="multiple">
      <option value="1">Football</option>
      <option value="2">Volleyball</option>
      ...
</select>
```

this way it'll give you `1,2,....`. Hope that's what you're looking for.

and if you're looking for query like this

```
INSERT INTO tb (`game`) VALUES ('Football'),('Volleyball')
```

assuming that `id` field is auto-incremented, then change the code as follows:
**html code**

```
<select name="game[]" multiple="multiple">
  <option>Football</option>
  <option>Volleyball</option>
  ...
</select>
```

**php code**

```
$choice=$_POST['game'];   
$sql = "INSERT INTO tb (`game`) VALUES ";
$sqlValues= null;
foreach($choice as $ch) {
    $sqlValues .= "('$ch')," ;                     
}
$sql.=rtrim($sqlValues, ",");                      
echo $sql;
```

this way you could get

```
id         game
1          cricket
2          football
```

Answer (score 0):

Are there any error messages being displayed? Insert the following code just before the mysql_query statement:

```
echo "insert into tb values('','$choice1')";
```

what is being displayed?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  $query=mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
  mysql_select_db("freeze",$query);
  $choice=$_POST['game'];
  $choice1=implode(',',$choice);
  foreach($choice1 as $choice) 
  {
     mysql_query("insert into tb values('','$choice')");
  }
}
?>
```

You just try this code i hope it works for you. If not then please reply me.

Comment: `$choice1=implode(',',$choice);` here implode will change the array `$choice` into string and you can't run `foreach($choice1 as $choice)`. So you don't need implode here...