# Insert Multiple Selection from Dropdown into one Row

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to take multiple selections from a drop down, and insert them into a single column/row in a table.

So that it would look like this (ColumnB):

```
ColumnA | ColumnB | ColumnC
---------------------------
Stuff   | A, B, C | Stuff
```

This is the dropdown:

```
echo "<select NAME='SysName_1' SIZE='1' multiple tabindex='7'>\n";
echo "<option>Choose One or More</option>\n";
```

To populate dropdown I use a select statement

```
$strSQL = "SELECT STATEMENT"; 

$rsSQL  = odbc_exec($connSQL,$strSQL) or die ('Error Executing Subsystems SQL');

$strOptions = "";

while ($row=odbc_fetch_array($rsSQL)){

   $id          = trim($row["SysName"]);
   $thing       = trim($row["SysDesc"]);
   $strOptions .= "<OPTION VALUE='$id'>$thing</option>";
}

echo $strOptions;

echo "</select>\n";
```

And this is what I have at my Insert:

Should combine multiple selections separated by , correct?

```
$SysName_1 = implode(',',$_POST['$SysName_1']); 

$SQLIN = 'INSERT INTO TABLE (COLUMNA) VALUES ($SysName_1)';
```

I tried doing what was located here, as his code seems to be doing what I want (although he doesn't want it to) [Multiple dropdown values inserting in a single row not in multiple row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18158798/multiple-dropdown-values-inserting-in-a-single-row-not-in-multiple-row)

But it does not work at all. I get an invalid argument for the implode in my server log, and the insert statement is just blank for that variable.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `name` attribute in your form needs to end with `[]` to indicate an array. This should work

```
echo "<select NAME='SysName_1[]' SIZE='1' multiple tabindex='7'>\n";
```

But you should be careful. Never trust user input! Don't insert the value from your `$_POST` directly into the db. Always escape at least

Comment: Awesome that put me on the right track. And when I looked back over my code after making the change you suggested, I saw that my $_POST['$SysName_1'] should have been $_POST['SysName_1'] so after doing your change, and seeing that mistake it is all working correctly. +1

Comment: Great to hear. Remember the vulnerability. I'm not familiar with odbc, but instead of `implode` I would loop through the array and escape the values properly

Comment: Aah ok. So even though it is pre-filled data from a drop down, some resourceful people can still stick stuff into the drop down that shouldn't be there? (I'm still fairly new to using PHP and don't know/understand all the stuff people can do to mess with things).

Comment: Correct. You can easily do this yourself nowadays by rightclick > inspect (or similar functionnames :P), e.g.